Delphi How to Decrypt data with public key
In my VCL application I send a request to server and receive a data that encrypted with private key using php openssl_private_encrypt. Now I want to decrypt it with a public key. I have the public key.
In RSA algoritm the public key is only used for encryption so all Delphi encryption components such as TMS Cryptography, Delphi-OpenSSL , etc... decrypt data with private key not public key using openssl. but the php openssl_public_decrypt decrypts the data with public key. How this php statement works? And What is Delphi equivalent of php openssl_public_decrypt statement?
How should I decrypt the data with public key using openssl?

What benefit has an encryption that can be decrypted with a key available to anyone? If you want bidirectional encrypted data, you can use private/public key pairs for the server and each client. Encryption is done at the sender with the public key of the receiver and decrypted with the private key at the receiver.

@UweRaabe, as to the benefit, I think this answer addresses it.

This is a common and unfortunate abuse of the notation. "Encryption" with a private key is really not encryption, it's signing. And "decryption" with a public key is not decryption, it's verifying.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk Yes you are right, but as openssl says the RSA_private_encrypt, RSA_public_decrypt functions handle RSA signatures at a low-level. so I want to implement this functions in my Delphi project.

libcrypto-3.dll exports the function RSA_public_decrypt() already
Delphi-OpenSSL is outdated, as it still relies on libeay32.
You could use a more recent implementation like Synapse which supports version 3.x but not everything of it right away. All you need to do is to import the functions you want to use yourself. Which shouldn't be a big issue: libcrypto-3.dll exports RSA_public_decrypt() already with a signature that is almost identical to what PHP does:

int RSA_public_decrypt(int flen, unsigned char *from, unsigned char *to, RSA *rsa, int padding);


This roughly translates to (untested):
type
  SslPtr = Pointer;
  PRSA = SslPtr;

function RSA_public_decrypt(flen: Integer; from, to_: PAnsiChar; rsa: PRSA; padding: Integer): Integer; cdecl;


Example on importing another TLS function into Synapse
Just edit ssl_openssl3_lib.pas and pick one of the functions to then imitate everything on it. In this example I've chosen EvpPkeyAssign - just search for every occurance of it and add similar code to the new function (RSA_public_decrypt) you want to import. Relevant parts of the file will now look like this and in every case you see first the existing code of EvpPkeyAssign and under it the new code for RSA_public_decrypt:
unit ssl_openssl3_lib;

interface

...
  function EvpPkeyAssign(pkey: EVP_PKEY; _type: integer; key: Prsa): integer;
  function RSA_public_decrypt(flen: Integer; from, to_: PAnsiChar; rsa: PRSA; padding: Integer): Integer;
...

implementation

...
type
...
  TEvpPkeyAssign = function(pkey: EVP_PKEY; _type: integer; key: Prsa): integer; cdecl;
  TRSA_public_decrypt = function RSA_public_decrypt(flen: Integer; from, to_: PAnsiChar; rsa: PRSA; padding: Integer): Integer; cdecl;
...

var
...
  _EvpPkeyAssign: TEvpPkeyAssign = nil;
  _RSA_public_decrypt: TRSA_public_decrypt = nil;
...

function EvpPkeyAssign(pkey: EVP_PKEY; _type: integer; key: Prsa): integer;
begin
  if InitSSLInterface and Assigned(_EvpPkeyAssign) then
    Result := _EvpPkeyAssign(pkey, _type, key)
  else
    Result := 0;
end;

function RSA_public_decrypt(flen: Integer; from, to_: PAnsiChar; rsa: PRSA; padding: Integer): Integer;
begin
  if InitSSLInterface and Assigned(_RSA_public_decrypt) then
    Result := _RSA_public_decrypt(flen, from, to_, rsa, padding)
  else
    Result := 0;
end;

...

function InitSSLInterface: Boolean;
var
  s: string;
  x: integer;
begin
...
  try
    if not IsSSLloaded then
    begin
      SSLUtilHandle := LoadLib(DLLUtilName);
      SSLLibHandle := LoadLib(DLLSSLName);
      if (SSLLibHandle <> 0) and (SSLUtilHandle <> 0) then
      begin
...
        _EvpPkeyAssign := GetProcAddr(SSLUtilHandle, 'EVP_PKEY_assign');
        _RSA_public_decrypt := GetProcAddr(SSLUtilHandle, 'RSA_public_decrypt');
...

function DestroySSLInterface: Boolean;
begin
  SSLCS.Enter;
  try
...
    _EvpPkeyAssign := nil;
    _RSA_public_decrypt := nil;
...


Thank you, But I don't know how to do it. Where is the libcrypto-3.dll? and how should I import the function from it? please help me.

What does "outdated" mean more precisely, in this context? Does decryption not work? Or are there security flaws? It's not obvious that just because it's outdated in general (lacks some newer features or such), it wouldn't work to use it for decrypting as wanted here.

@saeid2014 OpenSSL 3 binaries can be found here

@DaveNottage Yes I saw it but how should I import the RSA_Public_decrypt function from the openssl 3 dll ?

Wouldn't import DLL function in Delphi be a separate question to first study existing answers instead? And would looking at the linked .pas file and how it's done there for dozens of other functions help, too?
